# how to write a function that will take a linkedlist as a parameter? and return a linked list containing all ODD numbers?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have already created the linked list. but now I'm facing problem to pass the linked list as a parameter in a function and return a linked list containing all odd numbers from that linked list.

Comment: Consult the [std::forward_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) reference.

Comment: If you've already created it, you can show the code and what else you've tried, so that people have a useful level of information to respond to.

Comment: So, what, **exactly**, is the problem? Show us [mcve] of code you are having trouble with.

Comment: with [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3): `my_list | ranges::view::filter([](int e){ return e % 2 == 1; })`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
std::list<int> Remove_Odd_Numbers(const std::list<int>& original_list)
{
  std::list<int>  odd_list;
  std::list<int>::const_iterator  iter_begin(original_list.begin());
  std::list<int>::const_iterator  iter_end(original_list.end());
  std::list<int>::const_iterator  iter(original_list.begin());
  for (iter = begin_iter; iter != end_iter; ++iter)
  {
    if ((*iter & 1) == 1)
    {
      odd_list.push_back(*iter);
    }
  }
  return odd_list;
}
```

If you have a custom linked list, substitute your list type for `std::list`.

If you don't have iterators in your custom list, then use loop that visits each node.  Append a new node to the new list if the value in the node is odd.